# How to Setup Dynamic Columns for Dynamic DataSource for Ant Design Table

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have data structure like this:

```
{
  "units": [
    {
      "id": "000D3A2155A180E411E79A1A1E9C37AC",
      "name": "Unit 1",
      "ratings": [
        {
          "type": "Customer",
          "score": 84,
          "ratingType": 1
        },
        {
          "type": "Standards",
          "score": 44,
          "ratingType": 2
        },
        {
          "type": "Client",
          "score": 54,
          "ratingType": 3
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "000D3A2155A180E411E79C94155E4FA5",
      "name": "Unit 2",
      "ratings": [
        {
          "type": "Customer",
          "score": 76,
          "ratingType": 1
        },
        {
          "type": "Standards",
          "score": 44,
          "ratingType": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see I have dynamic part in my data structure in ratings field and I have trouble visualizing it. I've setup columns like this:

```
    const [columns, setColumns] = useState<ColumnsType<RatingUnit>>([
        {
            dataIndex: `name`,
            key: `id`,
            render: text => <div>{text}</div>,
        },
    ]);
```

I want to add column for each element in ratings array. To do so I get all unique ratingTypes present in this array:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const allUnitRatings = ratingUnits.map(unit => unit.ratings).flat();

        const uniqueRatingTypes = [...new Set(allUnitRatings.map(rating => rating.ratingType))];
        uniqueRatingTypes.forEach(ratingType => {
            setColumns(currentColumns => [
                ...currentColumns,
                {
                    dataIndex: [`ratings`],
                    key: ratingType,
                    render: text => <div>{text}</div>,
                },
            ]);
        });
    }, [ratingUnits]);
```

Now I need somehow match data in data structure to this columns like this:

```
Name   | RatingType 1 | RatingType 2 | RatingType 3 |
Unit 1 |     84       |      44      |      54      |
Unit 2 |     76       |      44      |      -       |
```

How I can match ratings array for each unit to corresponding columns by ratingType field?

Comment: Check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72686983/dynamic-antd-table-title-react/72727167#72727167. Is this what you are looking for?